# clicking on a post link leads to a blank page in php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, posts

I have been trying to learn PHP, and I am stuck at one point. I created some posts and made them as links, but on clicking them, they lead me to a blank page.

**Here is the index.php code**

```php
      <?php 
     while(have_posts()){
        the_post();?>
        <h2><a href="get_the_permalink()"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
```

**Here is the single.php code**

```php
    <?php 
     while(have_posts()){
        the_post();?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
```

I changed the `href` value to another working link, and it was working pretty well, the problem maybe with permalink. I went to WordPress `dashboard->permalink` and tried all kinds of common settings, but the problem still exists, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use PHP functions always wrapped inside `<?php` - `?>`

```
<?php 
 while(have_posts()){
    the_post();?>
    <h2><a href="<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
 }
?>
```